# How to use SSL on a distributed Spring Boot client calling a hosted web app

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a Spring Boot (2.x.x) service which customers can download. Once they've downloaded and started the service, they login to a managed portal to interact with the service.

The managed portal is hosted on Firebase, and setup with the default SSL certificates from Firebase. When viewing the managed portal in Chrome I can see `This page includes resources that were loaded with certificate errors.`.

If I attempt to view the managed portal from Firefox, the following exception is thrown in the Spring Boot service.

```
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:472) ~[netty-codec-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278) ~[netty-codec-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1408) [netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930) [netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:799) [netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.33.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:427) [netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.33.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:328) [netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.33.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905) [netty-common-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1647) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1615) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1781) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1070) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:896) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:766) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:295) ~[netty-handler-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1301) ~[netty-handler-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1203) ~[netty-handler-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1247) ~[netty-handler-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:502) ~[netty-codec-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:441) ~[netty-codec-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

From here, I'm sure I've got something wrong, but unsure what exactly.

The configuration for my service is:

```
server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:keystore.jks
    key-password: changeit
    key-alias: keystore
```

and I created the keystore using

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias keystore -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.jks -validity 3650
```

How can I clean up this so I get a nice green secure badge?

Answer (score 0):

In your `application.yml`, change `key-password` to `key-store-password`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add SSL Truststore and keystore certificates to your JVM using java properties during startup. I found this works with no fuss all the time.

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStore
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword
javax.net.ssl.trustStore
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword
```